# What does じいつにくうだらない mean?

Tags: translation

The phrase "じいつにくうだらない" appeared in the *Doraemon* manga, but the words don't appear in a dictionary. What is actually being said?

じいつ - ?

くうだらない - silly (?)

I would greatly appreciate help translating.

Comment: None of those are words, but it might be something like 実にくだらない

Comment: Yes I think you're right, I should have said I lifted in from a manga (Doraemon) so the words are probably being stretched for effect.

Comment: So these words were written this way? If so that is some very important context that will change how many people interpret the question.

Comment: Hindsight is a wonderful thing :) At the time I assumed they were proper words. If what I said is right, then I didn't realise words could be stretched using hiragana.

Comment: Sure! I edited the question a little bit to make it less of a "translate this" question as those get some negative attention here. Feel free to change it if you don't like my wording.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

じいつ - じつ = realy

くうだらない - くだらない = boring

Comment: I see, I wondered about that. As it's taken from a manga (Doraemon) I guess it's just stretching out the words for effect?